# Hilt getting lost with Application class of multi module app - Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I have an app with a main Module, and i'm trying to dissolve this app in a separated Module.

I'm getting an error when trying to implement Dependency Injection with Dagger Hilt in the 2th module.

The thing is:
In the Main Module, I have a class that extends from Application():

```
public class AndroidAppApplication extends Application() {
SEVERAL CODE HERE
}
```

In the second Module, I have a class that extends from Application to, that is required by Dagger Hilt:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class SecondModule : Application()
```

The error is that the Dagger Hilt is getting lost with this two classes.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Hilt Activity must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Application. Found: class br.com.somehere.androidapp.app.AndroidAppApplication

There's a way to tell Hilt that he have to look at the second class, not to first one?

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code.

```
@HiltAndroidApp   
    public class AndroidAppApplication extends Application() {
    SEVERAL CODE HERE
    }


 @AndroidEntryPoint
class SecondModule : Application()
```

Reference: [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#java)